# How to read this xml file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

Im reading an XML file with ajax. Everything is working, I have just no idea how to get the string out of the xml file. The xml file looks like this:

```
<file>
    <data>
        <name>Brittus</name>
    </data>
    <bank>
        <money id="1">10</money>
        <money id="2">25</money>
        <money id="3">40</money>
        <money id="4">60</money>
    </bank>
</file>
```

Now I would like to get the value of the tag money with the attribute 4. How can i get it with javascript?

```
file = responseObject.responseXML;
alert(file.getElementsbyTagName("money")[2].//an now?
```

And how to get the value of the money tag with id 2?

Thank you

Comment: I guess file.getElementsByName("bank")[0].getElementById(/*the id*/).nodeValue shoud work.

Answer (score 1):

try `file.getElementById('2')`?

Also why don't use use JSON instead..

Comment: I'm not aware of how browser handle it, but normaly getElementById() should not work on a XML-structure without a known namespace because it is unclear which attribute is an ID. Normally it is declared in the DTD.

Answer (score 1):

```
file.getElementsByTagName('money')[2].firstChild.nodeValue
```

The first Child of `<money>` is a textnode.